# Nested Constructors C++

Tags: c++, constructor, nested, sfml

I am using SFML and have a class like the following:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class Overlay
{
public:
    Overlay(int width, int height);
    Overlay(const sf::Texture*);
    Overlay(const sf::Sprite*);

    ~Overlay();

private:
    sf::Texture _texture;
    sf::Image _img;
};
```

Now the following constructor for `Overlay(const sf::Sprite*)` is working:

```
Overlay::Overlay(const sf::Sprite* spr) {    
    int width = spr->getTexture()->getSize().x;
    int height = spr->getTexture()->getSize().y;
    _texture.create(width, height);
    _img.create(width, height, sf::Color::Transparent);
}
```

However, the following, nested constructors are not:

```
Overlay::Overlay(int width, int height)
{
    _texture.create(width, height);
    _img.create(width, height, sf::Color::Transparent);
}

Overlay::Overlay(const sf::Texture* tex) {
    sf::Vector2u textureSize = tex->getSize();
    Overlay(textureSize.x, textureSize.y);
}

Overlay::Overlay(const sf::Sprite* spr) {
    Overlay(spr->getTexture());
}
```

To me it looks, like the two snippets should be doing the same thing if the following is executed:

```
sf::Sprite image;
Overlay mOverlay(&image);
```

Although both of them compile just fine, when the second code snippet (nested constructors) is called, `_img` ends up having a size of 0 and its `m_pixels` array is empty.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nested constructors". Were you expecting these constructor bodies to call other constructors on the same object? That's not how it works. You can't "call" a constructor like a function. All you're doing is creating some temporaries. Look up "delegating constructors" in your C++ book.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well that is...embarrassing...

Comment: Well, it happens :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Delegating Constructors.

It sounds like you are looking for a [Delegating Constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor).

To use a delegating constructor, it should appear in another constructor's *member initializer list*, not the constructor's *body*.

In your second snippet, you are constructing a temporary `Overlay` object the stack. When the constructor returns, the temporary is destroyed and has no effect.

Try defining the constructor like so:

```
Overlay::Overlay(const sf::Sprite& spr)
    : Overlay(spr.getTexture())
{
}
```

---

### A small code review.

Notice how I used a `const sf::Sprite&` rather than a `const sf::Sprite*`? Because the case of `spr` being a `nullptr` isn't being handled, it makes sense to pass it by reference to ensure it refers to an object. This also clears up any question as to who *owns* the texture after the constructor is called.

When you do this, you should also consider declaring the constructor with the [`explicit` keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) like so:

```
class Overlay
{
public:
    explicit Overlay(const sf::Texture&);
    explicit Overlay(const sf::Sprite&);
};
```

This prevents `Texture`s and `Sprite`s from accidentally being turned into `Overlay`s when passing them around.